# swapping characters in ex

Tags: vim, vi, ex

I am pretty new to vim and ex and I was wondering if anyone could help me with an area I am fuzzy on. I would like to know how to swap characters on every line or occurrence of a pattern. For example How would I swap the first 2 characters of every line in a file. I know it can be done and I'm pretty sure it involves the use of parentheses to store the chars. But thats is all I know. Also, Say I wanted to replace the 2nd char on everyline with some string, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace second character in each line to `r` in vim: `:%s/^\(.\)./\1r/`:

- `:%s/p/r/` replace pattern `p` with `r` for all lines (because of `%`);
- `^` start line;
- `\(` start a group;
- `.` any character (the first in this example);
- `\)` end the group;
- `.` any character (the second in this example);
- `\1` back reference to the first group (the first character in this example);
- `r` replacement text.

To swap two first characters: `:%s/^\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/`.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the first two characters on every line:

```
:%s/^\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/g
```

Replacing the second character on every line with  "string":

```
:%s/^\(.\)\(.\)/\1string/g
```

More info on the substitute command: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to swap the two first chars of every line in the buffer:

```
:%norm xp
```

or:

```
:%s/\v^(.)(.)/\2\1
```

You'll need the `:global` command to apply the commands above on every line matching a specific pattern:

```
:g/foo/norm xp
```

or:

```
:g/foo/s/\v^(.)(.)/\2\1
```

Reference:

```
:help :normal
:help :global
:help :s
:help range
```